Complex object cannot be retrieved from Room database: Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter
I'm using Room database and want to store complex object that is from 3rd party library.
What I have is:
@Entity(tableName = "messages")
@TypeConverters(
    ChatMessageContentConverter::class
)
data class MessageEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val id: String,
    val threadId: String,
    val content: ChatMessageContent? = null,
    val senderDisplayName: String? = null
)

Now.. ChatMessageContent is a library SDK object, so I use converter:
class ChatMessageContentConverter {

    private val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun toChatMessageContent(value: String?): ChatMessageContent? {
        return value?.let { gson.fromJson(value, ChatMessageContent::class.java) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromChatMessageContent(content: ChatMessageContent?): String? {
        return content?.let { gson.toJson(content) }
    }
}

At this point everything is fine, because when I store object in database, it works. However, when I want to retrieve all objects from this database, I only get like 2-3 objects and I see error:
error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create instance of class com.azure.android.communication.common.CommunicationIdentifier. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.

I dug deeper and found out that CommunicationIdentifier is actually from ChatMessageContent object.
public final class ChatMessageContent {
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("topic")
    private String topic;
    @JsonProperty("participants")
    private List<ChatParticipant> participants;
    @JsonProperty("initiatorCommunicationIdentifier")
    private CommunicationIdentifier initiatorCommunicationIdentifier;

    public ChatMessageContent() {
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public ChatMessageContent setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return this.topic;
    }

    public ChatMessageContent setTopic(String topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
        return this;
    }

    public List<ChatParticipant> getParticipants() {
        return this.participants;
    }

    public ChatMessageContent setParticipants(List<ChatParticipant> participants) {
        this.participants = participants;
        return this;
    }

    public CommunicationIdentifier getInitiatorCommunicationIdentifier() {
        return this.initiatorCommunicationIdentifier;
    }

    public ChatMessageContent setInitiatorCommunicationIdentifier(CommunicationIdentifier initiatorCommunicationIdentifier) {
        this.initiatorCommunicationIdentifier = initiatorCommunicationIdentifier;
        return this;
    }
}

The same object CommunicationIdentifier is inside ChatParticipant object, so what I need to do is write Converter for CommunicationIdentifier, to avoid the error.

Not sure how to do it properly, because with the following code I still receive the same error:
class CommunicationIdentifierConverter {

    private val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun toCommunicationIdentifier(value: String?): CommunicationIdentifier? {
        return value?.let { gson.fromJson(it, CommunicationIdentifier::class.java) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromCommunicationIdentifier(identifier: CommunicationIdentifier?): String? {
        return identifier?.let { gson.toJson(identifier) }
    }
}

and add the:
@TypeConverters(
    ChatMessageContentConverter::class,
    CommunicationIdentifierConverter::class
)

and this still causes the same error

I believe that the issue is not a Room type converter issue, but, as per the message, a java Type Adapter/constructor issue where the CommunicationIdentifier cannot be built from the JSON.

@MikeT What's the best solution in cases like these? I ended up to create completely Custom object class and extract all information I needed from Java message class, stored it in my custom class and it worked fine, but it was extra time and I would've expected that it just works right away with no other object implementation/mapping/parsing.

Best way would be according to opinion. e.g. from relational DB perspective a table per object with relationships and thus most likely to be normalised. Perhaps from JSON perspective utilising a library, if one, that copes. From class perspective perhaps suitable classes and constructors, which appears to be the approach you have taken.   I'd personally go the table per object which would eliminate the need for Type converters but likely at the expense of more complicated and lengthier coding.
